# give a user access rights to a folder

Tags: permissions

i've searched on the web for an answer to my issue but what i find just raises more questions.

I have installed plexserver on my ubuntu 14.04.

Plex can't see files or folders from my media library.

There is a plex user and a plex group on my system.  When i give plex the ownership of my media files (Chown) everything is fine. But that is not what i want. I just want to give plex read and write rights to my media folder. Is this possible with chmod? if yes how? if no, then i what is the cleanest way to give plex read and write rights to my media folder?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the right way to give access to servers like these (apache, plex, etc.) is to change the group of the folder and give group permissions accordingly. For example, consider apache (for which the corresponding user and group is `www-data:www-data`), I'd do:

```
chown $USER:www-data public_html -R
chmod g+w <relevant folders>
```

Replace `www-data` with the plex server's group. Thus, you retain the ultimate ownership of the files, while being able to grant plex the necessary level of access.